# Integrate $\int \frac{1}{x^4+4}dx$

Tags: calculus

> Integrate $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{x^4+4}dx$.

I could try breaking this up into two quadratic trinomials, but that seems like it would be a lot of work. If that is the best way here how do I do it most efficiently?

Comment: What's so hard about factoring into irreducible quadratics, then using partial fractions, then completing the square (twice), then substitution (twice), then... oh I get it. ;p

Comment: "...but that seems like it would be a lot of work." Unfortunately, I'm not sure there's any way to get around that. This is definitely a bite-the-bullet kind of problem and I would attempt what user Bye_World has suggested above.

Comment: You could always just use an [integral table](http://www.sosmath.com/tables/integral/integ17/integ17.html), though.

Comment: WolframAlpha http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=\int+\frac{1}{x^4+4}

Comment: For a detailed solution, see the appropriate .pdf file at [this 14 October 2009 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6868513). See also these two math stackexchange questions: [how to solve $\int\frac{1}{1+x^4}dx$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/973822/how-to-solve-int-frac11x4dx) and [Integration of $\int\frac{1}{x^{4}+1}\mathrm dx$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160157/integration-of-int-frac1x41-mathrm-dx).

Comment: Related math stackexchange questions: [Evaluate $\int\frac{1}{1+x^6} \,dx$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1007399/evaluate-int-frac11x6-dx) and [Help with $\int\frac{1}{1+x^8}dx$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446902/help-with-int-frac11x8dx) and [How can I evaluate this indefinite integral? $\int\frac{dx}{1+x^8}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/875840/how-can-i-evaluate-this-indefinite-integral-int-fracdx1x8).

Comment: Two more related math stackexchange questions: [Solving this integral?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/777263/solving-this-integral) and [How to find the indefinite integral $\int \frac{dx}{1+x^{n}}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742173/how-to-find-the-indefinite-integral-int-fracdx1xn?).

Answer (score 7):

Notice
$$\frac{1}{x^4+4} = \frac{1}{(x^2+2)^2 - 4x^2}
= \frac{1}{(x^2+2x+2)(x^2-2x+2)}$$
Since
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{x^2-2x+2} - \frac{1}{x^2+2x+2} &= \frac{4x}{(x^2+2x+2)(x^2-2x+2)}\\
\frac{1}{x^2-2x+2} + \frac{1}{x^2+2x+2} &= \frac{2x^2+4}{(x^2+2x+2)(x^2-2x+2)}
\end{align}$$
We have

$$\frac{1}{(x^2+2x+2)(x^2-2x+2)}
= \frac14\left[\frac{1-\frac{x}{2}}{x^2-2x+2} + \frac{1+\frac{x}{2}}{x^2+2x+2}\right]\\
= \frac18\left[\frac{x+2}{x^2+2x+2} - \frac{x-2}{x^2-2x+2}\right]
= \frac18\left[\frac{(x+1)+1}{(x+1)^2+1} - \frac{(x-1)-1}{(x-1)^2+1}\right]
$$
Up to an integration constant, this give us
$$\begin{align}
\int\frac{dx}{x^4+1}
&= \frac{1}{16}\log\left(\frac{(x+1)^2+1}{(x-1)^2+1}\right)
+ \frac18 \left[\tan^{-1}(x+1)+\tan^{-1}(x-1)\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{16}\log\left(\frac{(x+1)^2+1}{(x-1)^2+1}\right)
+ \frac18 \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{2-x^2}\right)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 4):

I did it like this. You can Complete it Easily after this.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to avoid partial fractions, you can do it this way:

Expand in Taylor series (convergent for $|x| < \sqrt{2}$):
$$ \dfrac{1}{4+x^4} = \dfrac{1/4}{1 + x^4/4} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{4^{n+1}} x^{4n} $$
Integrate term-by-term
$$ \int \dfrac{1}{4+x^4} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{4^{n+1}} \dfrac{x^{4n+1}}{4n+1} = \dfrac{x}{16} \text{LerchPhi}\left(-\dfrac{x^4}{4},1,\dfrac{1}{4}\right)$$
where 
$$ \text{LerchPhi}(z,a,v) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{z^n}{(n+v)^a}$$
Of course you might want to convert that LerchPhi expression to something
more elementary...

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\int\frac{1}{x^4+4}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int\frac{1}{\left(x^2-2x+2\right)\left(x^2+2x+2\right)}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int\left(\frac{2-x}{8(x^2-2x+2)}+\frac{x+2}{8(x^2+2x+2)}\right)\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\frac{1}{8}\int\frac{2-x}{x^2-2x+2}\space\text{d}x+\frac{1}{8}\int\frac{x+2}{x^2+2x+2}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\frac{1}{8}\int\frac{2-x}{x^2-2x+2}\space\text{d}x+\frac{1}{8}\int\left(\frac{2x+2}{2(x^2+2x+2)}+\frac{1}{x^2+2x+2}\right)\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\frac{1}{8}\int\frac{2-x}{x^2-2x+2}\space\text{d}x+\frac{1}{8}\int\frac{1}{x^2+2x+2}\space\text{d}x+\frac{1}{16}\int\frac{2x+2}{x^2+2x+2}\space\text{d}x=$$

---

For the integrand $\frac{2x+2}{x^2+2x+2}$, substitute $u=x^2+2x+2$ and $\text{d}u=(2x+2)\space\text{d}x$:

---

$$\frac{1}{8}\int\frac{2-x}{x^2-2x+2}\space\text{d}x+\frac{1}{8}\int\frac{1}{x^2+2x+2}\space\text{d}x+\frac{1}{16}\int\frac{1}{u}\space\text{d}u=$$
$$\frac{1}{8}\int\frac{2-x}{x^2-2x+2}\space\text{d}x+\frac{1}{8}\int\frac{1}{x^2+2x+2}\space\text{d}x+\frac{\ln\left|u\right|}{16}=$$
$$\frac{1}{8}\int\frac{2-x}{x^2-2x+2}\space\text{d}x+\frac{1}{8}\int\frac{1}{x^2+2x+2}\space\text{d}x+\frac{1}{16}\int\frac{1}{u}\space\text{d}u=$$
$$\frac{1}{8}\int\frac{2-x}{x^2-2x+2}\space\text{d}x+\frac{1}{8}\int\frac{1}{x^2+2x+2}\space\text{d}x+\frac{\ln\left|x^2+2x+2\right|}{16}=$$
$$\frac{1}{8}\int\frac{2-x}{x^2-2x+2}\space\text{d}x+\frac{1}{8}\int\frac{1}{(x+1)^2+1}\space\text{d}x+\frac{\ln\left|x^2+2x+2\right|}{16}=$$

---

For the integrand $\frac{1}{(x+1)^2+1}$, substitute $s=x+1$ and $\text{d}s=\text{d}x$:

---

$$\frac{1}{8}\int\frac{2-x}{x^2-2x+2}\space\text{d}x+\frac{1}{8}\int\frac{1}{s^2+1}\space\text{d}s+\frac{\ln\left|x^2+2x+2\right|}{16}=$$
$$\frac{1}{8}\int\frac{2-x}{x^2-2x+2}\space\text{d}x+\frac{\arctan\left(s\right)}{8}+\frac{\ln\left|x^2+2x+2\right|}{16}=$$
$$\frac{1}{8}\int\frac{2-x}{x^2-2x+2}\space\text{d}x+\frac{\arctan\left(x+1\right)}{8}+\frac{\ln\left|x^2+2x+2\right|}{16}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Question: Evaluate $$\int \frac{1}{x^4 + 4}$$**

**Solution(A bit long winded but uses elementary techniques):**

First, notice that $$\frac{1}{\left( x^2 - 2x + 2 \right) \left( x^2 + 2x + 2 \right)} = \frac{Ax + B}{x^2 - 2x + 2} + \frac{Cx + d}{x^2 + 2x + 2}$$ Breaking this up we have
\begin{align}
1 &= \left( x^2 + 2x + 2 \right) \left( Ax + B \right) + \left( x^2 -2x + 2 \right) \left( Cx + d \right) \\ &= Ax^3 - 2Ax^2 + 2Ax + Bx^2 - 2Bx + 2B + Cx^3 + 2Cx^2 + 2Cx + Dx^2 + 2Dx + 2D \\ &= \left(A + C \right)x^3 + \left( B + 2C + D - 2A \right)x^2 + \left( 2A - 2B + 2C + 2D \right)x^1 + \left( 2B + 2D \right)x^0
\end{align}

We can compare coefficients to produce $4$ equations.

\begin{align}
A + C = 0 \tag{1}\label{eq1} \\ B + 2C + D - 2A = 0 \tag{2}\label{eq2} \\ 2A - 2B + 2C + 2D = 0 \tag{3}\label{eq3} \\ 2B + 2D = 1 \tag{4}\label{eq4}
\end{align}

Solving this system we find that $A = -\frac{1}{8}, B = \frac{1}{4}, C = \frac{1}{8}, D = \frac{1}{4}$

Therefore, $$\frac{1}{\left( x^2 - 2x + 2 \right) \left( x^2 + 2x + 2 \right)} =  \frac{- \frac{1}{8}x + \frac{1}{4}}{\left(x - 1 \right)^2 + 1} 
 + \frac{\frac{1}{8}x + \frac{1}{4}}{\left( x + 1 \right)^2 + 1}$$ and so $$\int \frac{1}{x^4 + 4} = \int \frac{- \frac{1}{8}x + \frac{1}{4}}{\left(x - 1 \right)^2 + 1} + \int \frac{\frac{1}{8}x + \frac{1}{4}}{\left( x + 1 \right)^2 + 1}$$

We can Say that $$\int \frac{1}{x^4 + 4} \, dx = I_1 + I_2$$ Where $$I_1 = \int \frac{- \frac{1}{8}x + \frac{1}{4}}{\left(x - 1 \right)^2 + 1} \quad \textrm{and} \quad I_2 = \int \frac{\frac{1}{8}x + \frac{1}{4}}{\left( x + 1 \right)^2 + 1}$$

---

**Finding $I_1$.**

$$I_1 = \int \frac{-\frac{1}{8}x + \frac{1}{4}}{\left( x - 1 \right)^2 + 1}$$ let $u = x - 1$. Therefore, $$\int \frac{-\frac{1}{8}\left( u + 1 \right) + \frac{1}{4}}{u^2 + 1} = \int \frac{- \frac{1}{8}u + \frac{1}{8}}{u^2 + 1} = \int \frac{- \frac{1}{8}u}{u^2 + 1} + \int \frac{\frac{1}{8}}{u^2 + 1} = -\frac{1}{8} \int \frac{u}{u^2 + 1} + \frac{1}{8} \int \frac{1}{u^2 + 1}$$

By the reverse chain rule and using the standard integral for $\arctan$ we have $$\boxed{I_1 = -\frac{1}{16} \ln \left( u^2 + 1 \right) + \frac{1}{8} \arctan \left(u \right)}$$

---

**Finding $I_2$.**

$$I_2 = \int \frac{\frac{1}{8}x + \frac{1}{4}}{\left( x + 1 \right)^2 + 1}$$

Let $v = x + 1$. Therefore, $$\int \frac{\frac{1}{8}\left( v - 1 \right) + \frac{1}{4}}{v^2 + 1} = \int \frac{ \frac{1}{8}v + \frac{1}{8}}{v^2 + 1} = \int \frac{\frac{1}{8}v}{v^2 + 1} + \int \frac{\frac{1}{8}}{v^2 + 1} = \frac{1}{8} \int \frac{v}{v^2 + 1} + \frac{1}{8} \int \frac{1}{v^2 + 1}$$ By the reverse chain rule and using the standard integral for $\arctan$ we have $$\boxed{I_2 = \frac{1}{16} \ln \left( v^2 + 1 \right) + \frac{1}{8} \arctan \left(v \right)}$$

---

Since $$\int \frac{1}{x^4 + 4} = I_1 + I_2$$ we finally have $$\boxed{\int \frac{1}{x^4 + 4} = -\frac{1}{16} \ln \left( (x - 1)^2 + 1 \right) + \frac{1}{8} \arctan \left( x -1 \right) + \frac{1}{16} \ln \left( (x + 1)^2 + 1 \right) + \frac{1}{8} \arctan \left( x + 1 \right)}$$

Once again, I know this isn't the best answer, but it seemed fun to utilise so many concepts to solve one question.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?