# Evaluating $\int_0^{D}\frac{1}{x^{a}+1}dx$ for Different Values of $a$?

Tags: integration, polynomials

I am trying to simplify an integration expression

$$\int_0^{D}\frac{1}{x^{a}+1}dx$$

I know that for $a=2$, I can have it as $\arctan(x)$. But what about the general case?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What about PFD , Partial Fraction Decomposition ?

Comment: How can I decompose it?

Comment: Just Read a Mathematics Textbook, By the way you can try this http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=ec4a062bb304f88c2ba0b631d7acabbc

Comment: Is $a$ an integer?

Comment: not sure, $a$ might not be an integer.

Comment: I think wolfram cannot solve my problem with general $a$.

Comment: If you want the most general answer for any real $a$, it is given in terms of **Hyper Geometric** function $I = \int {{1 \over {{x^a} + 1}} = } x\,\,{}_2^{}F_1^{}\left( {1,{1 \over a};1 + {1 \over a}; - {x^a}} \right)$

Comment: For positive integer values of $a,$ see [Solving this integral?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/777263/solving-this-integral).

Comment: @Cardinal Your suggestion of partial fractions is not useful. Prove me wrong with a full answer for general $a$ or even just arbitrary positive integer $a$ if you think otherwise.

Comment: @I didn't assert that it is the most general case. This integral can be solved through confluent hypergeometric function, as mentioned by H.R